# How to re render Modal in react Functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm using **Ant Design Pro UI** library in my frontend.

When I click the edit button I want to set **defaultValues** to my Modal input fields. But when I click edit first time it works fine and defaultValues come in correct form.

After that when I close my Modal and click the Edit button then same results appear in the Modal. The problem is that the Modal hides and **it isn't re-rendering**.

```js
{visi && (
        <Modal
          title="Edit Plan"
          visible={visi}
          onCancel={() => {
            hideModal();

            if (!showDetail) {
              setCurrentRow(undefined);
            }
          }}
          okButtonProps={{ style: { display: 'none' } }}
          cancelButtonProps={{ style: { display: 'none' } }}
          bodyStyle={{ width: 400 }}
          values={currentRow || {}}
        >
          <Form form={form} layout="vertical" name="addNewPlan" onFinish={handleUpdate}>
            <FormItem name="id" hidden initialValue={singlePackage ? singlePackage.id : null}>
              <Input placeholder="Basic Plan" style={{ width: '33vw', marginTop: -10 }} />
            </FormItem>
            <FormItem
              name="name"
              label="Plan Name"
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input plan name!',
                },
              ]}
              initialValue={singlePackage ? singlePackage.name : null}
            >
              <Input placeholder="Basic Plan" style={{ width: '33vw', marginTop: -10 }} />
            </FormItem>
            <FormItem
              name="description"
              label="Description"
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input description!',
                },
              ]}
              initialValue={singlePackage ? singlePackage.description : null}
            >
              <TextArea
                allowClear={true}
                style={{ marginTop: -10, width: '33vw' }}
                placeholder="The Basic Plan having this kind of features and you can Send 300 email in a day."
              />
            </FormItem>
            <FormItem
              name="campaign_count"
              label="Campaign Count"
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please input campaign count!',
                },
              ]}
              initialValue={singlePackage ? singlePackage.campaign_count : null}
            >
              <Input style={{ width: '33vw', marginTop: -10 }} type="number" />
            </FormItem>
            <FormItem>
              <div style={{ width: '33vw' }}>
                <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" style={{ float: 'right' }}>
                  <span>Update</span>
                </Button>
                <Button type="default" onClick={hideModal} style={{ float: 'right' }}>
                  <span>Cancel</span>
                </Button>
              </div>
            </FormItem>
          </Form>
        </Modal>
)}
```

If anyone knows how to re-render Modal in React, please help me.

Comment: add `setVisi(false)` on hideModal()

Comment: I already did that but it is doing only hide the Modal. If i re render the Modal same data are visible in the input fields. i want to re render my Modal.

Comment: Can you please provide us the problem example in codesandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-mountain-5y50es?file=/src/App.js this is the code

Comment: @Muditha your above codesandbox link does not have the Modal code, can you please check and share the link again?

Comment: @Ved Sorry about that. Now code is there. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `resetFields` method of form instance.

```
const [form] = useForm();

return (
  <Modal onCancel={() => {
    hideModal();
    form.resetFields();
  }}>
    <Form form={form}>...</Form>
  </Modal>
)
```

[Check out this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ31w.png)